# Serilog Application Insights Sink is showing Requests but not Traces

Tags: azure-application-insights, serilog

I am using the serilog application insights sink in a .NET project and it is showing requests but not traces in the Azure portal.

The application insights telemetry window in VS shows local app insights which is showing the requests and traces but in the azure portal I can only see requests.
I have tried to use the minimal configuration to get it working but I just cant see traces at all. I have a file sink which shows the log messages and the requests.
What am I missing?

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
.CreateLogger();

builder.Host.UseSerilog(logger);

builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

_logger.LogInformation("Test Log Entry");
```

The config file I am using:

```json
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=XXXX",
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
    ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "O:\\logs\\log1.log",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] [{SourceContext}] [{EventId}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 20000000,
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the configuration file in the  text format.

Comment: How you have configured serilog in Program.cs file?

Comment: `builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();` is not enough to trace logs using serilog.

Comment: Iam able to log [traces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbTCa.png).Will post an answer in detailed.

Comment: `var Conn = builder.Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights").GetValue<string>("ConnectionString");

var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
 .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(Conn, new TraceTelemetryConverter())
 .CreateLogger();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(log);
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

app.Logger.LogInformation("Log Information from Program class file");
app.Logger.LogWarning("Log warning from Program.cs");`

Comment: Use the above code and try..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially even I got the traces only in Local, unable to send traces to Application Insights.

[image]

- I have used the same configuration which you have shared, done changes in the `Program.cs` file.
- To log requests/Traces using `Serilog`, we need to use the `LoggerConfiguration`.
- Install the below NuGet Packages

```cs
Serilog
Serilog.AspNetCore
Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights
```

***My `.csproj` file:***

```cs
 <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="3.0.1" />
 <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="6.1.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights" Version="4.0.0" />
```

- Iam able to log the traces using the below code.

***My `Program.cs` file:***

```cs
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var Conn = builder.Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights").GetValue<string>("ConnectionString");

var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
 .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(Conn, new TraceTelemetryConverter())
 .CreateLogger();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(log);
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

app.Logger.LogInformation("Log Information from Program class file");
app.Logger.LogWarning("Log warning from Program.cs");
---
}
```

***Traces in Application Insights:***

[image]

Comment: If you want to use configuration from appsettings , then use  `.ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)` only.Just log the traces after the build using `app.Logger.LogInformation("Hello")`;

Comment: Thank you Harshitha, it worked I just needed to add .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(Conn, new TraceTelemetryConverter()) to the LoggerConfiguration and I can see the traces now. You just made my day! Thanks!!!!